# java stream writing batch String in to file

Tags: java, java-8, stream

Am having a `list` object having String values which i want to write it into a file by batch-by-batch.

In my below code, am having batch value as 4. so, am expecting to write 4 string values into the file from batch-1. Next batch (batch-2) it should write other 4 string values.

But its not working as expected.

Please find the my code below.

```
public class WriteToFile {
    
    public static void batches(List source, int length) throws IOException {
        if (length <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("length = " + length);
        int size = source.size();

        int fullChunks = (size - 1) / length;
            
        try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(
                Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Karthikeyan\\Desktop\\numbers.txt")))) {
            IntStream.range(0, fullChunks + 1).mapToObj(String::valueOf).forEach(pw::println);
            
    }
    

}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");

        
        System.out.println("By 4:");
        batches(list, 4);
    }

}
```

Below contents are writting in my file.

```
0
1
```

It should write :

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

In batch.

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
int fullChunks = (size - 1) / length;
```

Will result in 6 - 1 / 4. Because these are ints it is rounded downwards so the result will be 5/4 = 1.

In IntStream you take the range form 0, 2 (to upper limmit is not part of the range) so 2 elements resulting in 0, 1. If you want the value from the list itself than use `mapToObj(i -> source.get(i).toString())` instead of `.mapToObj(String::valueOf)`

It is not clear what you want you want to accomplish with batches, because the results are all written to the same file.

Comment: In real time, my input `list` object will contain 600K records which i will fetch from external system from webservice. So i want to write all the `600K` records into a file so my taught is to write it as batch-by-batch. in-order to avoid any failure while writing. This is my idea behind.